# Binary trees and doubleTree() function

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-tree, mirror

I recently learned about binary trees and decided to practice a bit. I thought I understood pointers and reference parameters quite decently, but then I came across this code:

```
 void doubleTree(struct node* node) { 
  struct node* oldLeft;

  if (node==NULL) return;

  // do the subtrees 
  doubleTree(node->left); 
  doubleTree(node->right);

       // duplicate this node to its left 
     oldLeft = node->left; 
     node->left = newNode(node->data); 
     node->left->left = oldLeft; 
    }
```

I simply can't understand how it's possible to change the construction of a binary tree without using reference parameters or a non-void function.

I've been searching the internet for days and haven't found a decent explanation.
I understand that I don't need reference parameters when I'm working with existing nodes but as far as I understand, this is the same as creating a new element and adding it to the binary tree - where I **had** to use a non-void function!

Could anybody please explain this to me?

Comment: Since the code never assigns to `node` (only to `node->left` or `node->left->left`), you already have pointers to the data you're changing.  If you assigned to `node`, then you'd have problems andb you would need `struct node **nodeptr` in the arguments, and `*nodeptr = …` and you'd call `doubleTree(&node->left)`, etc.

Comment: This is everything I wanted to know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in C there are no reference parameters at all... All parameters are passed *by value*.  For that reason, pointers come at hand.... and you get passed to the function a *pointer to the root node of the subtree, which is itself a reference to the root node.*  **This is indeed the reference you expect**, but expressed as a pointer to node.

## NOTE

In the case you show, the problem could arise if you had to change the pointer passed (you cannot change it as it is passed **by value**) to the root node of the subtree, as changing the pointer will happen only locally in the subroutine.  In that case you can pass a double pointer, as in

```
void doubleTree(struct node** node) { ... }
```

so you pass actually a pointer to the root pointer holding the address of the root node.   Modifying it should be done with:

```
*node = foo ...;
```

and so, you'll have a reference to the root pointer.  But the stuff done in the routine deals only with the node contents and the children of the root node.... nothing with the pointer to it, so you don't need to pass a reference to the pointer at all.

## NOTE 2

There's a problem with the code shown, apart from the question you make.  The doubled node is supposedly appended as the grandson left->left child, without checking if the left child actually has a left children.  In the case that the left child actually has a left child, the subtree at that point will be substituted by the newly created node, generating a memory leak (all that subtree will be unreachable from now on) and changing that subtree to a single node.  Strange behaviour for a routine supposed to double a tree.

Personally I agree with you that using a function that returns the copied tree would be nicer and simpler to write:

```
struct node* doubleTree(struct node* node) 
{ 
    return node != NULL
        ? newNode(node->data, 
                  doubleTree(node->left), 
                  doubleTree(node->right));
        : NULL;
}
```

(in this case `newNode()` has three parameters, the node data, the left and right children to attach to it)

## NOTE 2

I suppose the intent of storing the doubled node as a child of the root given node is some trick to save the built tree as a subtree of the given one.  But it fails for the reason stated above, so you need to actually return a pointer to be able to give something back to the calling code.
The intent of the code of passing up a blank node with references to the old and new trees fails, as when called recursively, it should lead to all subtrees constructed in this way also, an the tree finally would be populated by blank copies of supporting left and right copies of original and copied subtrees.  You should need a recursive routine as the one written above, returning a reference to the new created subtree.

You where right in this point :)